# Discarding more than one commit in TortoiseHg

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am using TortoiseHg.
I did a false commit, and then another false commit.
Both commits are in draft state (not yet pushed).
I want to completely ignore this commits and go back as if they where never committed.

Doing Rollback seems to only remove the last commit.
How can I do that simple task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In settings enable either the `mq` or `strip` extension, then in a changeset context menu use `Modify History -> Strip`

Comment: Strip in modern Mercurial isn't part of MQ extension

Comment: @LazyBadger the question was mostly about tortoisehg, which requires enabling `mq`

Comment: Wrong! I **have** in THG `hg strip` without enabling MQ

Comment: @Lazy Badger: could you please show it somehow? I disabled it and in `v3.2.3` (the latest stable) I have it disappeared. https://www.dropbox.com/s/xpwgx0bhqo0qhb3/Screenshot%202015-01-11%2022.15.38.png?dl=0 --- here is a screenshot of a context menu for arbitrary changeset (that's where I suppose to see the menu item)

Comment: @LazyBadger And here is a screenshot after I **enable** the `mq` extension: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3gh5be2v8crmhvj/Screenshot%202015-01-11%2022.19.33.png?dl=0 So, uhm, I'm not sure how you can get it working in a TortoiseHG without it

Comment: @LazyBadger https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/4021/strip-menu-is-not-available-if-no-other --- please check. Your "Wrong" thing is wrong, sorry.

Comment: **YOU have** to re-check this issue and RTFM http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StripExtension

Comment: @Lazy Badger: that's correct - you still need to enable **EITHER** `mq` or `strip`

Answer (score 0):

You can rollback twice for two bad commits

**Follow-up to discussion with @zerkms**

MQ contained strip to Mercurial (TortoiseHG) before 2.8. Now it's [independent extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StripExtension), which have to be enabled in Extensions (see 1) without MQ (see 2)

[image: Extensions]

and after it Strip will appear in "Modify history" menu of context-menu for changeset

[image: Menu]

Comment: You could swap 1 and 2 and get the same results. It's either that provides the corresponding facilities. If you checked it (instead of being rude) then you wouldn't need to post another answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In a recent mercurial (since v2.8 I think), you can make changesets obsolete which hides them from most views, yet they are still there if you find you ever want them. This is the recommended way to do what you want.

Lets say the most recent changeset is 132 and the latest good change is 130. Simply make changesets 131 & 132 obsolete like this:

```
hg prune -r 131::132
```

Couldn't be simpler (just make sure the current parent isn't one of the unwanted changesets).

If you find you want to see the contents of the obsolete changesets, just add --hidden to the normal command line, e.g.:

```
hg log -r 120::132 --hidden
```

NB. Tortoise has a feature to view obsolete changesets, but I don't believe it yet has the ability to make them obsolete.